# Deep Learning 2D-Convol Layer: When does the Channel =1?

Tags: deep-learning

Sorry if this sounds basic. But for input_shape, understand that the channel =3 for colored images.

But for black-white and grey-scale images, channel =1?

Thank you

````
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(4,4),input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu',))
input_shape = image_height, image_width, channels

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed correct, when talking about single images a colored RGB image has three channels (R, G, and B) and a black and white has one channel indicating the pixel luminance.